# Enable Modules on Package Install

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I am developing a Joomla extension with a component, multiple modules and a plugin. I was wondering if there is a way to automatically enable the Modules from the package as soon as its installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the the first things that pop into my mind is is using the postflight() method in your [extension script file](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file).

Inside it you can just do an SQL query on `#_extensions` setting `enabled =1` for your module.

Looking forward to seeing other ideas.

Comment: However, this will only set the status of the module to Published. Is there a way to setup its position and menu assignments programmatically this way or these things differ from install to install and from theme to theme?

Comment: Each theme can define it's own positions. You can get this for core templates to work, maybe for popular themes builders. If you want to look more into it, checkout under administrator/com_modules/models/module.php save() method. Calling this method and passing the $data you want, may just work. Also for experienced webmasters, working with templates, modules and positions is not something new - so think if it's worth the trouble.